# Apache pyspark ML example not working

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying the ML example (IndexToString) on this web page:http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder, using jupyter notebook (running Pyspark) to create a simple df (dataframe), and I keep getting a long error message. One of the lines said:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.applySchemaToPythonRDD.
>   : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Please help, does this mean I need to have a RDD first to build a DataFrame? Also, I tried the MLlib methods and it worked fine, it's the ML methods that keep giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of spark are you using? the example in your link require spark 2.0.0

In this link, you can find example for spark 1.6.2 - which was tested to be working on my machine
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/ml-features.html#onehotencoder

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (0, "a"),
    (1, "b"),
    (2, "c"),
    (3, "a"),
    (4, "a"),
    (5, "c")
], ["id", "category"])

stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="category", outputCol="categoryIndex")
model = stringIndexer.fit(df)
indexed = model.transform(df)
encoder = OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol="categoryIndex", outputCol="categoryVec")
encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
encoded.select("id", "categoryVec").show()
```

Comment: I was using Spark 2.0.0